# Apple Pay Merchant Identifier missing edit link

Tags: applepay

Not a coding question per se, but I can't think of anyone apart from other devs who would know this.

It's time for me to update my Apple Pay merchant identity and payment processing certificates. The first step is to go to the Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles page and edit the appropriate certificate, but none of them have an edit link, either on the listing or when I click through, despite being signed in with the account that created and owns the certificates. I can download, I can revoke, but I cannot edit.

Has anyone else seen this and is there a solution? Creating new identities is a much more involved process than simply renewing a certificate[1], so I'm keen to avoid going down that route.

Many thanks.

[1] in itself, a ridiculous faff

Comment: You can see the answer from an Apple dev here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649205?page=1#613535022 (basically as accepted answer below, create new and swap it out, but with more detailed steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not support renew of payment processing certificate. You need to create a new CSR and upload and activate it.

Comment: Thanks - Apple Support said the same thing and provided a procedure, which I'll paste in here.